# Не выводит числа из указанного мною диапазона (Java)

Tags: java

//1 случай

```
public class Main { 

   public static void main(String args[]){
    
      
      int random_number1 = 0 + (int) (Math.random() * 10);
      System.out.println("случайное число: " + random_number1); 
      //здесь все правильно выводит
```

//2 случай

```
public class Main { 

   public static void main(String args[]){
    
      
      int random_number1 = 1960 + (int) (Math.random() * 1985);
      System.out.println("случайное число: " + random_number1);
      //здесь выводит намного больше например 3250
      // может в этом методе какие то свои особенности, не знаю
```

Comment: Во втором случае у вас диапазон от 0 до 1985. И ещё добавляете 1960

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Получить случайное число в диапазоне

```
public static double getRandomDoubleBetweenRange(double min, double max){
   double x = (Math.random()*((max-min)+1))+min;
   return x;
}
```